# Starting Java applet directly from jar file

Tags: jar, applet

The goal is to have an applet run from a jar file.

The problem is that the applet only seems to want to run from an exploded jar file.

Samples on the Internet suggest this applet tag:

```
  <applet code="com.blabla.MainApplet"
          archive="applet.jar"
          width="600" height="600">
```

This will not even try to look in the jar file and fails with:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://localhost:8080/helloWord/com/blabbla/MainApplet.class
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 ... 7 more
```

Setting the codebase instead of the archive attribute to the jar file. Looks a bit better. However, the JVM does not realize that it has to open the jar file:

```
  <applet code="com.blabla.MainApplet"
          codebase="applet.jar"
          width="600" height="600">


Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://localhost:8080/helloWord/applet.jar/com/blabbla/MainApplet.class
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 ... 7 more
```

How does the applet tag have to be formulated to start an applet class from *inside* of a jar file?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the Java console was caching previous bad jars. Once the cache was cleared in the Java console, the first version of the code worked fine.

```
<applet code="com.blabla.MainApplet"
          archive="applet.jar"
          width="600" height="600">
```