# Jar file generation from single class file

Tags: java, jar, applet

I have an applet file which just displays hello world statement.How could i generate a jar file using the simple one class file that i am having.

I tried creating it from command line using the command **jar cvfe hello.jar hello *.class**

But when i tried executing the jar file,there is no applet being displayed.

Comment: use a jar generator to generate a jar. a simple implementation of it is ant  but you can use zip utility.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run directly from command page or from an HTML page?

1. In the first case you should look
   here:[Starting Java applet directly from jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604034/starting-java-applet-directly-from-jar-file)
2. In the second case you should have a look here:
   [Java Applet in JAR File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982935/java-applet-in-jar-file)

Hope this helps.